# Flex direction column but two of the children next to each other with different order for desktop

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

This is part of a responsive design in which the layout is `flex-direction: row` for desktop and it has to be `flex-direction: column` for mobile. BUT, the two elements `one` and `three` have to be next to each other instead of on top of each other. (you can't put them in a container separately as that will break the desktop layout).

Is there any way to achieve this with Flexbox?

```css
.flex-container-desktop {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.two {
  order: 1;
}

.three {
  order: 2;
}

.one {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<b>Desktop</b>
<div class="flex-container-desktop">
  <div class="child one-desktop">
Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child two-desktop">
Child 2
  </div>
  <div class="child three-desktop">
Child 3
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<b>Mobile</b>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="child one">
Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child two">
Child 2
  </div>
  <div class="child three">
Child 3
  </div>
</div>

<br>
Child 3 and 1 should be next to each other only on mobile.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with `flex-direction: row` and media queries. So when its mobile view you change order and make first element take full width with `flex: 0 0 100%` and two other elements `50%`. Also its important to set `flex-wrap: wrap` so two other elements go to next row.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .two {
    order: 1;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .three {
    order: 2;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
  .one {
    order: 3;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="child one">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child two">
    Child 2
  </div>
  <div class="child three">
    Child 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be the most logical option.

Comment: aha. I was "media-querying" the flex-direction from row to column and then was trying to find a way to make the 2 children go side by side with flex-basis .. but apparently "column" was stronger than width :).